# Problem setting state via props in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a problem but I could not find out what the cause is, I believe it is related to my lack of experience with react, well let's go. When the component is mounted the componentDIdMount is called and inserts the state of the props, but when I refresh the page (f5) the unit and timezone states do not receive the value of the didMount, but the state test receives its value, it is as if this.pros did not exist in componentDidMount but it is on the component.

> **When the component is rendered.**

[image]

> **When refresh to page (f5).**

[image]

**I see that componentDidMount is called in refresh because the test is inserted into the state, but this.props is not. Does anybody point the light at the end of the tunnel?**

> **My component.**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ActionsCreators from '../../redux/actions/actionsCreators'

class MyAccount extends Component{ 
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            unit: '',
            timezone: '',
            test:''
        }
    }   
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            unit: this.props.auth.user.unit,
            timezone: this.props.auth.user.timezone,
            test:'test'
        })
    }
    render(){ 
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>MyAccount</h1>
                <span>state {JSON.stringify(this.state)}</span>              

                <br/>
                <span>props unit:{JSON.stringify(this.props.auth.user.unit)} </span>
                <br />
                <span>props timezone:{JSON.stringify(this.props.auth.user.timezone)} </span>           
            </div>             
        )
    }
} 
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        updateProfile: (user) => dispatch(ActionsCreators.updateProfileRequest(user))
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyAccount)
```

Comment: Could it be that component is being mounted before `state.auth` has a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when you refresh the page your component is getting mounted *before* your redux state is filling in. Thus, when `componentDidMount` fires, there's nothing in redux, so the props are nil. When redux finally fills in, it re-renders, causing the props to appear in the component. I would recommend taking a look at [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) (which replaced the old `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle event in React 16.3). You can use that to set the state whenever new props come in. Dropping something like this in your component should work:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
  if(nextProps.someValue!==prevState.someValue){
    return { someState: nextProps.someValue};
  }
  else return null;
}
```

This example was lifted from [this article](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607) which I've found to be a good primer on how this new react event works.

Comment: Do it feeling, I'll check and then I'll give you feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to track changes in props and update state accordingly

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
 return (nextProps.auth !== this.props.auth ||
         nextState.unit !== this.state.unit ||
         nextState.timezone !== this.state.timezome);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.auth !== this.props.auth) {
    this.setState({
      unit: this.props.auth.user.unit,
      timezone: this.props.auth.user.timezone
    });
  }
}
```

This way if the props are arriving after `componentDidMount` state will be updated

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe that the [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607) method is more appropriate to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is useful, Try this...

```js
import _isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

if(!_isEqual(this.props.auth.user, nextProps.auth.user)){
this.setState({
            unit: this.props.auth.user.unit,
            timezone: this.props.auth.user.timezone,
            test:'test'
        })
}
}
```